# Why can't nullables be declared const?

Tags: c#, null, constants, nullable

```
[TestClass]
public class MsProjectIntegration {
    const int? projectID = null;
    // The type 'int?' cannot be declared const
    // ...
}
```

Why can't I have a `const int?`?

**Edit:** The reason I wanted a nullable int as a const is because I'm just using it for loading some sample data from a database. If it's null I was just going to initialize sample data at runtime. It's a really quick test project and obviously I could use 0 or -1 but `int?` just felt like the right data structure for what I wanted to do. readonly seems like the way to go

Comment: I really can't think of a case where you would need to have a constant of value null. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: Best practice: Use constants only for things which are *logically constant for all eternity*. Good: the number of items in a dozen, the year Elvis was born, the atomic number of lead. Bad: version numbers -- they change from version to version; things which change should not be constants. Terrible: the current yen-to-euro exchange rate; changes every second.

Comment: yea i was basically just using it as an ad hoc config file, definitely not best practice

Comment: <humor>Should that not be "Yea verrily! I was basically . . ." </humor>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not just nullables; only types built into the runtime can be declared `const` (from memory, it's bools, the various types of int, floats/doubles, and strings).

Why? Because the value gets embedded directly into the assembly at compile time, and there's no way to embed user-defined types.

The `readonly` keyword should do what you need, however. By contrast with `const`, any `readonly` fields get initialized at runtime rather than compile time, so they can be initialized with more or less any expression you want.

**Edit:** as Eric Lippert points out, it's not this straightforward. For instance, `const decimal` works.

This:

```
private const decimal TheAnswer = 42;
```

...compiles (well, Reflectors) to this:

```
[DecimalConstant(0, 0, (uint) 0, (uint) 0, (uint) 42)]
private static readonly decimal TheAnswer;
```

Comment: thanks, the assembly part was enlightening and made this the best answer (to me)

Comment: This is not correct. First: decimals are not a built-in type but they can be const.  Second: yes, there are ways to embed constant user-defined types; we *chose* to not implement this feature. It's certainly *possible* in principle. (Proof: we did it for decimal.)

Comment: ha, when i asked this question i wasn't expecting a response from someone from the c# compiler team

Comment: This is one of the reasons why stackoverflow is so badass.

Comment: @EricLippert if decimal isn't built in type, how is compiler able to infer its value and do simple checks right at compile time? ie if you do `const decimal d = 0;` and `if(d == 1)...` the compiler warns that `if` is always false. The value comparison is made right there.

Comment: @nawfsl decimal is special in c#. But from the clr point of view it is just another struct.

Comment: One wonders what makes the items in the "allowed as const" list so special; other immutable types besides String should be perfectly okay to use as const. Like Color and DateTime; both of those are basically just wrappers around a bare int too, after all (respectively an Int32 and an Int64).

Answer (score 13):

http://en.csharp-online.net/const,_static_and_readonly

> Constants must be of an integral type
>   (sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int,
>   uint, long, ulong, char, float,
>   double, decimal, bool, or string), an
>   enumeration, or a reference to null.
>
> Since classes or structures are
>   initialized at run time with the new
>   keyword, and not at compile time, you
>   can't set a constant to a class or
>   structure.

Since nullable is a struct, the above quote is the reason why.

Answer (score 9):

You can't have a const reference type (or a struct), therefore you can't have a const int? which is really just a `Nullable<int>.`

You can mark it as readonly

```
readonly int? projectID = null;
```

Then it can't be modified outside the class constructors.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is not a reference type, but a struct. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using the "readonly" modifier instead.

`const`s are evaluated at compile time, whereas `readonly`s are enforced at run time.  Instances of complex types cannot be compiled into the assembly, and so must be created at runtime.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is not a reference type, but a struct. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're basically saying:

> I have a class with a projectId field
>   that may or may not have a value, but
>   that in fact NEVER has a value, it's
>   is always undefined.

From a logical point of view... the declaration itself makes no sense.

Comment: because its a config setting that could be null and i would rather not code around a magic number.... say -1

Comment: If projectId is "const" you cannot be loading anything into it from the database... in fact you can't do almost anything with it.

Comment: How can a primary key be null?

Comment: var project = projectID.HasValue ? Project.GetProjectByID(projectID.Value, connectionString) : new Project();

Comment: Sure it makes sense. For example, in a unit test that uses DataRowAttribute. I'd like to declare my test data like 
    private const int? NullStudentId = null;  
    private const int ZeroStudentId = 0;  
    private const int ValidStudentId = 100;  
Then in [DataRow] use my consts (cannot use readonly must be const) like 
    [DataRow[NullStudentId)]  
    [DataRow(ZeroStudentId)]  
    [DataRow(ValidStudentId)]  
Unfortunately I cannot do that. I need to use null instead of NullStudentId. That's one valid use of a const int?.