# Why is it not possible to declare a constant of type System.Drawing.Color?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, constants

Since I use "System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro" in multiple places in my app:

```
if (tb.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro)) {
```

...I wanted to make it a constant. But when I tried:

```
const System.Drawing.Color PSEUDO_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
```

...I got, "The type 'System.Drawing.Color' cannot be declared const"

???

Comment: Same reason as for this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1833589/525558)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only types that can be `const` are those that have a literal representation in C#, as references to the constant are replaced at compile time with the literal value. There is no literal way to represent a color (you can only obtain a color either by a factory method or, as you are, using one of the `static` pre-existing colors).

You can, however, use a `static readonly` variable to achieve the same effect.

```
static readonly Color PSEUDO_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = Color.Gainsboro;
```

For more info, see section 10.4 of the C# Language Specification

> The type specified in a constant declaration must be `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, `string`, an enum-type, or a reference-type.

For reference types, the only valid values are either a string literal or `null`.

Comment: One wonders what makes the items in that list so special; other immutable types besides String should be perfectly okay to use as const.

Comment: FWIW -- While this is marked as the answer, I feel like it's relevant to point out that you actually CANNOT use "static readonly" as a universal drop-in replacement for a CONST. Primarily, as I'm struggling with at the moment, you can't use "static readonly" properties as default values in method declarations, but you can use CONSTs...

Answer (score 6):

> User-defined types, including classes, structs, and arrays, cannot be
>   const

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

[System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) is a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4(v=vs.71).aspx), which [cannot be declared constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590796/why-cant-structs-be-declared-as-const).  Try using `static readonly` instead, or use the [KnownColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309947/declare-color-as-constant) enumeration.

Comment: +1 for `KnownColor`, since that *can* be `const`, though it's a little more typing to use `FromKnownColor` every time.